# How do I open this secret room?

Tags: castlevania-symphony-of-the-night

Near the beginning of the game, there is a room full of mermen.  The completed map shows a secret room connected at the bottom left of this area.  I have heard stories about using the wolf/bat and [this tunnel](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg69/scaled.php?server=69&filename=epsxe2010013115050809sm.png&res=medium) to unlock it.  Sometimes they say you need to ram the ledge on the wall.  How do I gain access to this room in both castles?

[image]

Here is a screenshot from the inverted castle:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started a new game to test this: you don't need wolf form at all, nor can it be done without bat form.

Assuming you've opened the tunnel in the middle of the room (as indicated by the image you linked to), you just need to turn into bat form and fly through the tunnel, hugging the top of the tunnel.

This video illustrates the general principle: